# How to take year 2016 onwards?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code below working fine w/o the condition in the line `payrollEndDate = p.PayrollEndDate.Value.Year >= 2016` because it gives me an error `Invalid cast from 'Boolean' to 'DateTime'.` and the code that I added is return a boolean

```
var per = (from p in db.Periods select new { periodId = p.PeriodId, periodStart = p.StartDate, periodEnd = p.EndDate, payrollEndDate = p.PayrollEndDate.Value.Year >= 2016 });
var periods = (from p in per.AsEnumerable() select new { perId = p.periodId, PayrollEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(p.payrollEndDate).ToShortDateString() }).AsQueryable();
ViewBag.PeriodEndDate = new SelectList(periods, "PayrollEndDate", "PayrollEndDate", null);
```

How to take the year 2016 onwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` is for projections, not filtering. It sounds like you want a `where` clause instead. I'd suggest not using query expressions here, given that you're only doing simple things:

```
var query = db.Periods
              .Where(p => p.PayrollEndDate != null &&
                          p.PayrollEndDate.Value.Year >= 2016)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(p => new {
                  p.PeriodId,
                  PayrollEndDate = p.PayrollEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
              });
```

(I strongly suspect you don't actually want the `AsQueryable()` call there... it may give the *impression* that any further querying will be done in the database, but that would be an illusion, given that you've got `AsEnumerable()` already.)

I've removed the `Convert.ToDateTime` call as I'm assuming `p.PayrollEndDate.Value` is already a `DateTime`.

Comment: how to order by it in asc order? sorry I don't know how to lambda

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw: You use `.OrderBy(p => p.Foo)` or whatever. I strongly urge you to become familiar with LINQ in both forms - you shouldn't have to rely on query expressions for every LINQ query.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can i ask if you don't mind?. I have a 4 same value of date `6/15/2016` but the other 3 value is not in order they appear in the very last of query after the `12/30/2020` I don't know why.

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw: I'm afraid you haven't given enough context for me to know what the problem is - but I suggest you ask a *new* question with more information.